# Mockito says arguments are not identical but they are?

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, session, mockito

This is the method that I want to test:

```
public class SelectionVariantUniqueConstraintValidatorImpl implements UniqueConstraintValidator {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<Criteria> buildValidationCriteria(Object entity, Serializable id, String[] propertyNames) {
        final SelectionVariant selectionVariant = (SelectionVariant) entity;
        final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(SelectionVariant.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("client", selectionVariant.getClient()));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("variant.variantName", selectionVariant.getVariant().getVariantName()));

        return new ArrayList<Criteria>(Arrays.asList(criteria));
    }

    @Required
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

And this is my test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SelectionVariantUniqueConstraintValidatorImplTest {

    SelectionVariantUniqueConstraintValidatorImpl selectionVariantUniqueConstraintValidator
            = new SelectionVariantUniqueConstraintValidatorImpl();

    @Mock
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    @Mock
    private Session session;
    @Mock
    private Criteria criteria;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        selectionVariantUniqueConstraintValidator.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Test
    public void testBuildValidationCriteria() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(session);
        Mockito.when(session.createCriteria(SelectionVariant.class)).thenReturn(criteria);
        SelectionVariant selectionVariant = new SelectionVariant();
        Client client = new ClientBuilder().businessKey("HPD").description("desc").version(0).id(1L).build();
        selectionVariant.setClient(client);
        selectionVariantUniqueConstraintValidator.buildValidationCriteria(selectionVariant, null, null);
        Mockito.verify(criteria,Mockito.atLeastOnce()).add(Restrictions.eq("client", selectionVariant.getClient()));
    }
}
```

And this is what I see in the console:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
criteria.add(
    client=Client{id=1, businessKey='HPD', description='desc', version=0}
);
-> at com.innflow.ebtam.dao.hibernate.variant.SelectionVariantUniqueConstraintValidatorImplTest.testBuildValidationCriteria(SelectionVariantUniqueConstraintValidatorImplTest.java:48)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
criteria.add(
    client=Client{id=1, businessKey='HPD', description='desc', version=0}
);
-> at com.innflow.ebtam.dao.hibernate.variant.SelectionVariantUniqueConstraintValidatorImpl.buildValidationCriteria(SelectionVariantUniqueConstraintValidatorImpl.java:36)
```

What am I missing?

Edit:

equals method in Client.java is as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || (getClass() != o.getClass() && !(o instanceof Client))) return false;

    Client client = (Client) o;

    if (businessKey != null ? !businessKey.equals(client.getBusinessKey()) : client.getBusinessKey() != null)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Edit:

hashCode method in Client.java :

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return businessKey != null ? businessKey.hashCode() : 0;
}
```

Edit:

This makes the test work:

```
Mockito.verify(criteria,Mockito.atLeastOnce()).add(Restrictions.eq("client", Mockito.any(Client.class)));
```

Comment: I guess you forgot to implement equals and hashCode methods in Client.java

Comment: @RadoslawGrebski Added the equals method.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I do not understand your sentence, sorry. But I added some more information to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument to `criteria.add` is not a `Client`, but the return value of [Restrictions.eq](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#eq%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29), a [SimpleExpression](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/criterion/SimpleExpression.html).

`SimpleExpression` inherits its .equals-method from `Object`, so since you construct a new one in your test, the two arguments are not equal, even though they contain the same `Client`.

A way to compare the arguments the way you intend is to implement an `org.hamcrest.Matcher` like this:

```
class SimpleExpressionMatcher extends ArgumentMatcher<SimpleExpression> {
    private SimpleExpression simpleExpression;

    public SimpleExpressionMatcher(SimpleExpression simpleExpression) {
        this.simpleExpression = simpleExpression;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object argument) {
        @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
        SimpleExpression otherSimpleExpression = (SimpleExpression) argument;
        // somehow compare the SimpleExpressions, possibly like this:
        // this.simpleExpression.toString().equals(otherSimpleExpression.toString());
    }
}
```

Then verify like this:

```
 Matcher<SimpleExpression> matcher = new SimpleExpressionMatcher(Restrictions.eq("client", selectionVariant.getClient()));
 Mockito.verify(criteria).add(Mockito.argThat(matcher));
```

Comment: @KorayTugay sorry, i dont understand your question. Does Mockito.verify(criteria).add(Mockito.any(Client.class)) not fail your test?

Comment: No it does not. When I use Mockito.any(Client.class)) test will succeed.

Comment: Does the Client-class implement org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion (the class of the argument to criteria.add)? If it does not, the line in my previous comment should not even compile.

Comment: No it does not implement Criterion. It does compile. I have edited the question and added the statement how I made the test work.

Comment: @KorayTugay I've created a minimum working example: http://ideone.com/YTepmF i'm using Hibernate 4.1.3 and Mockito 1.9.5. Could you compare my results (see comments in the code) to yours if you run it?

Comment: Your example does not compile in my env as well but my test does compile and succeeds. Please see: http://1drv.ms/1GM15h6

Comment: OK, i dont think this is the way Mockito.any is supposed to be used - note that you can supply any object to criteria.add and your test will pass (literally: try it with criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("not client", new Object()))). This is strange behaviour by Mockito though. I'd advise to not use your variant, since it doesnt actually test what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, how can I fix this test then?

Comment: @KorayTugay see the variant in my answer (it's also in that minimum working example) using Mockito.argThat and an org.hamcrest.Matcher. This is the best way i've found to use Mockito.verify with objects without a custom .equals-method. You may want to find a better way to compare SimpleExpressions than via their .toString-representations, though, depending on your definition of equality in this case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76985/discussion-between-bewusstsein-and-koray-tugay).